# How can I use feof with while loop?

Tags: c, file, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I want to get student name mid-term and final points and write them in a txt file but when I use a loop, It never get student name. It always gives it a miss. How can I use feof with a loop? I want to get student names mid-term and final point and calculate the average from the got points and It must get always name and points till user press the end of file.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
FILE *Points;

char namesOfStudents[10];
int pointsOfStudents[1][2];
double AverageOfStudents[1];
int i=0,j=1;
int numberOfStudents;

Points = fopen("C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\Desktop\\PointsOfStudent.txt", "a+");
fprintf(Points, "Name\t\t 1.Grade\t2.Grade\t\tAverage\n");
/*  printf("How many students will you enter: ");
scanf("%d",&numberOfStudents);*/

//while (!feof(Points))

printf("Please enter new students name: ");
gets(namesOfStudents);
printf("\nPlease enter new students first point: ");
scanf("%d",&pointsOfStudents[0][0]);
printf("\nPlease enter new students second point: ");
scanf("%d",&pointsOfStudents[0][1]);


        for (; i < strlen(namesOfStudents); i++)
            {
                fprintf(Points, "%c", namesOfStudents[i]); //To write 
     student name to file

            }
        fprintf(Points,"\t\t   ");

        fprintf(Points,"%d\t\t",pointsOfStudents[0][0]);  //to write 
student's first point
        fprintf(Points,"%d\t\t",pointsOfStudents[0][1]);  //to write 
student's second point  

        fprintf(Points,"%d\n",(pointsOfStudents[0][0]+pointsOfStudents[0]
[1])/2);    //to calculate and write average 
        system("cls");

        fclose(Points);

system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: [Relevant question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Several things:

First, ***NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER*** use `gets` - it is dangerous, it *will* introduce a point of failure and/or massive security hole in your code, and it has been removed from the standard library as of the 2011 version of the language standard.  Use `fgets` instead:

```
fgets( nameOfStudents, sizeof nameOfStudents, stdin );
```

Secondly, `while( !feof( fp ) )` is always wrong. On input from `fp`, it will loop one time too often.  On output to `fp`, it is meaningless.

You can use the result of `fgets` to control your loop:

```
while ( fgets( nameOfStudents, sizeof nameOfStudents, stdin ) )
{
  ...
}
```

When you're done entering data from the terminal, signal an EOF using either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (depends on your platform).

Third, `main` returns `int`, not `void`; use

```
int main( void )
```

instead.

Finally, change

```
for (; i < strlen(namesOfStudents); i++)
{
  fprintf(Points, "%c", namesOfStudents[i]); //To write student name to file
}
```

to

```
fprintf( Points, "%s", nameOfStudents );
```

to write the student name to the file.

There are other problems, but make those changes and see if that doesn't help.